# Create zip files using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of files and I want to create a zip file out of this array.

Is there a way to create zip files using jQuery?

Comment: jquery is a dom traversing and manipulation library. There are js libraries (e.g. [JSZip](http://stuk.github.io/jszip/)) that can do this but i would suggest to do this serverside.

Comment: What is the problem with googling.. I just copy-past you question in google and get the example http://viralpatel.net/blogs/create-zip-file-javascript/

Comment: @ShreyosAdikari sir I tried that JSZip but unfortunately instead of zip files I get .file extension only so I need to rename it to .zip

Answer (score 5):

You can use the JSZip library mentioned by several people to create the zip. However, forcing a download from javascript and having it use a custom filename is a different matter.

HTML5 introduces a `download` attribute on `<a>`s. You could use it like this:

```
<a href="your_zip_data_uri_here" download="something.zip">download</a>
```

Which would force the download as "something.zip" in browsers supporting the download attribute. However, besides this, there is no way to do it from JavaScript.